# How can I change a Spark WindowedApplication StatusBar skin programatically?

Tags: css, apache-flex, statusbar, skin

Currently I'm using the ideas in [this post](http://jdls-flexism.blogspot.com.au/2011/07/flex-40-status-bar-skinning.html) to skin my s:WindowedApplication, so in the declaration of my component I have `skinClass="StatusBarSkin1"`. Also in my preinitialize function I have a method which puts the correct text onto the status bar using the label, which works fine.

The problem arises when I try and set the `skinClass` in my CSS, so I can change between `StatusBarSkin1` and `StatusBarSkin2`. So I'm doing something like:

```
Style1.css
----------

.mainWindow
{
     skinClass: ClassReference("StatusBarSkin1");
}


Style2.css
----------

.mainWindow
{
     skinClass: ClassReference("StatusBarSkin2");
}
```

If I do this, the theme loads fine, but the text for the status bar won't display; and if I set the theme in the WindowedApplication itself, then I can't change the skin on the status bar when I change CSS files using a method.

Is there a better way to implement this than what I'm doing now?

**EDIT**:

The statusbar object is just an `HGroup` with some labels and stuff in it.

The statusbar skin is given by this code:

```
<s:Group id="statusBar"
     width="100%"
     minHeight="20">

<!-- status bar fill -->
    <s:Rect left="0"
            right="0"
            top="0"
            bottom="0">
            <s:fill>
                <s:LinearGradient rotation="90">
                    <s:GradientEntry color="0x575757" />
                    <s:GradientEntry color="0x373737" />
                </s:LinearGradient>
            </s:fill>
    </s:Rect>

<!-- status bar highlight -->
    <s:Rect left="1"
            right="1"
            top="1"
            bottom="0">
            <s:stroke>
                <s:LinearGradientStroke rotation="90"
                                        weight="1">
                    <s:GradientEntry color="0x575757" />
                    <s:GradientEntry color="0x373737" />
                </s:LinearGradientStroke>
             </s:stroke>
    </s:Rect>

<!-- status text -->
<!--- @copy spark.components.WindowedApplication#statusText -->
    <s:Label id="statusText" />

    <s:Group id="statusBarSkin" />

</s:Group>
```

and then my preinit function is

```
private function InitStatusBar():void
{
    statusGroup = new StatusBar();
    (statusBar as Group).addElement(statusGroup);
}
```

Comment: I'm not following the problem you're having.  If I understand; the problem is that when switching the theme [at runtime] the WindowedApplication loses the value stored in the 'label' property?  Is that correct?

Comment: So I have a component called "StatusBar" which is basically just an `HGroup`, and in the skin I have the `statusBar` group (which I've edited into my question) - my preinit function adds "StatusBar" as a child of `statusBar`, if that makes sense.

Comment: I think the problem is that it's trying to draw the background over the group or something.